# Fill a Buffer with random values C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I took over a program with a variable: **static uint_8t *buffer** declared globally that I need to fill with up, but not with just one repeating value.  It doesn't have to be too "random", just full and not repeating.  I am using this buffer to run read10 scsi command tests on a HDD.  I am using visual c++ 2012.  Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If randomness doesn't matter too much, you might consider something like `std::rand` with a handy algorithm:

```
std::generate_n(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, std::rand);
```

The fact that your buffer's element type is unsigned means that overflow is safe. Here's a [sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5727dd98010824d983260499ddbfa62c-8a676986784bd3a58ce3ec015645a41f), though I suspect your code might be a bit different ;).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the values being consecutive, you could use [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota):

```
#include <numeric>

std::iota(buffer, buffer + SIZE, 0);
```

This will fill it with consecutive values starting from 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
const size_t N = 100; // your number of elements
for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    size_t tmp = i % std::limits<uint8_t>::max();
    buffer[i] = static_cast<uint_8t>(tmp)
}
```